Querying TypePal TModel in Rascal (code generation)
Is there a way to Query the typepal’s tmodel to facilitate code generation? How does that look like?

Yes, you can, it all depends a bit on your language how much extra stuff you might have to collect during typechecking.
After the TModel is constructed, it has all kinds of fields on there. Combining those with a visit of the original parse tree should get you going.

Nice! What if I parsed/implode the syntax into AST (ADT using the implode function), while doing the type collection at the Parse tree (Concrete syntax tree), is it still possible to still get query the TModel in this scenario? A nice example might be useful, Thanks.
